# Short Story about stomach possession by a demon

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I read a short story in the late 70's about a hungry man watching people eating at an inn and begins to reflect on his lifes misfortunes. He then encounters a stranger who offers him a lifetime of free food and drink in exchange for his stomach.  Every night thereafter his stomach is hijacked by a demon who eats and drinks in excess and he suffers the effects of the over indulgences the next morning.  Before long he starts to regret his decision as his life is in mortal danger.

Comment: I have the self same problem every weekend, usually early on a Sunday morning